# Simplify CSS with Sass ( making circle with small circles in css )

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to make some animation. With 8 small circle i make a big circle. This is my css code on how i placed my circles. There is a way to simplify this css  with Sass ( mixin, loops, or functions ) ?

```
span:nth-child(1) {
   margin-top: -100px;
}
span:nth-child(2) {
   margin-top: -70px;
   margin-left: 70px;
}
span:nth-child(3) {
   margin-left: 100px;
}
span:nth-child(4) {
   margin-top: 70px;
   margin-left: 70px;
}
span:nth-child(5) {
   margin-top: 100px;
}
span:nth-child(6) {
  margin-top: 70px;
  margin-left: -70px;
}
span:nth-child(7) {
  margin-left: -100px;
}
span:nth-child(8) {
  margin-top: -70px;
  margin-left: -70px;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `@for` loop:

```
$steps: -100px, -70px, 0, 70px, 100px, 70px, 0, -70px;

@for $n from 1 through 8 {
  span:nth-child(#{$n}) {
    margin-top: nth($steps, $n);
    margin-left: nth($steps, ($n + 1) % 8 + 1); // This is explained in the comments
  }
}
```

### Update: using trigonometry

You may well like to use trigonometry to calculate `top` and `left` values precisely based on the value of `$n` (you can find trig functions in a number of Sass extensions, such as Compass, or Google for details on rolling your own), which would make for cleaner code.

If you do have access to `pi`, `sin` and `cos` functions (such as by using Compass), you can calculate the precise values for positions around the circle based on `$n`:

```
@for $n from 1 through 8 {
  span:nth-child(#{$n}) {
    margin-top: 100px * sin($n * pi() / 4);
    margin-left: 100px * cos($n * pi() / 4);
  }
}
```

The `* pi() / 4` converts our `$n` values of `1`..`2`..`3`.. to `PI/4`..`PI/2`..`3PI/4`.. which are the radian equivalents of `45 degrees`..`90 degrees`..`135 degrees`.. which is exactly what we need.

### Update 2: flexible number of small circles

Made it slightly more flexible – no longer limited to 8 small circles:

```
$number-of-circles: 13;

@for $n from 1 through $number-of-circles {
  span:nth-child(#{$n}) {
    $angle-in-radians: $n * (pi() * 2 / $number-of-circles);
    margin-top: 100px * sin($angle-in-radians);
    margin-left: 100px * cos($angle-in-radians);
  }
}
```

`pi() * 2` is the radian equivalent of 360 degrees. We divide this by the number of circles (which gives the angle, in radians, between each circle), and multiply this by `$n` to get a radian angle value for each circle.

Working demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/grfFD

Comment: It works :). Thank you . @Shai Can you explain me the margin-left line please ?

Comment: @SalmenBejaoui The left margin uses `($n + 1)` instead of `$n`, to keep the left margins one ahead of the top margins in the `$steps` array (so that `top / left` will be `-100 / -70`, then `-70 / 0`, etc, rather than `-100 / -100`, then `-70 / -70`, which would give a diagonal line rather than a circle). The second half of that slightly confusing calculation `($n + 1) % 8 + 1` is just to wrap back to the beginning of `$steps`: instead of getting the 9th value from `$steps` (which doesn't exist) we wrap back to the 1st value. Google "modulo arithmetic" for more details. Does that help?

Comment: Thank you some much, i understand it.

Comment: @SalmenBejaoui no problem. Also updated to use trigonometry, allowing for precise positioning of any number of small circles (not just 8)